# Disk Encryption: Takes 30 seconds to 2 minutes to prompt for the password

Tags: boot, password, encryption

I recently purchased a computer and installed Ubuntu 22.04 onto it. After installing, I am having an issue where it takes a long time for the prompt to ask for a password comes up.

After I enter the encryption password the computer boots up in seconds, leading me to believe there is something wrong with the boot loader, maybe taking a long time to initialize graphics? Searching the internet results in information related to after entering the password, rather than before.

Running `systemd-analyze blame` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain` look sane comparatively to previous installs as well as another machine I have (I am guessing this is timing after it decrypts)

I am looking for any help that can be provided, thank you.

Comment: Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: I should have added that to the original post, that only shows messages from the time after the encrypted volume was mounted. The information I need to get/see is going to be before the password is entered for the encrypted volume to see what may be going on. Thank you though!

Comment: Are there any logs in the bios you can check?

Comment: There wasn't, @JiminyCricket. However, I was able to find the issue (added as an answer). Boiled down to the way this machine handled the GPU. Thank you for the suggestions and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems related directly to this particular computer (ROG Flow Z13). I booted to windows and switched the graphics card to "Standard" from "Dedicated" in the Armoury Crate App which caused the password prompt to show immediately after reboot. However, it then caused my system to stall on a black screen.

I then blacklisted the `nouveau` drivers by creating a file called `/etc/modprobe.d/block-nouveau.conf` with this as the content:

```
blacklist nouveau
alias nouveau off
```

After doing another reboot, this resolved the issue with a slow prompt. I suspect it was trying to load the dedicated gpu which took must longer to initialize and load compared to the integrated gpu.